# how can I remove the notification from the plugin "cordova-plugin-mauron85-background-geolocation"

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

In my application I do not want to show the notification or this type of messages to the user. I want you not to show up. How can I do it?

this is my configuration:

```
BackgroundGeolocation.configure({
locationProvider: BackgroundGeolocation.ACTIVITY_PROVIDER,
desiredAccuracy: BackgroundGeolocation.HIGH_ACCURACY,
stationaryRadius: 50,
distanceFilter: 50,
notificationTitle: 'Background tracking',
notificationText: 'enabled',
debug: true,
interval: 10000,
fastestInterval: 5000,
activitiesInterval: 10000,
url: 'http://192.168.81.15:3000/location',
httpHeaders: {
  'X-FOO': 'bar'
},
// customize post properties
postTemplate: {
  lat: '@latitude',
  lon: '@longitude',
  foo: 'bar' // you can also add your own properties
}
});
```

[image: indice]
[image: indice2]

Comment: Do you find a solution for that?I want to remove it but how?disable notification is solution ?

Comment: I cant do it...

Comment: do you use same plugin for IOS?For IOS background not working for that plugin @yavg

Answer (score 1):

The toast notification is for debugging.

You can turn it off like this:

> debug: false,

Answer (score 0):

change debug true to false, like this. To unshow messages of debug log.

```
BackgroundGeolocation.configure({
...
debug: false,
...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
BackgroundGeolocation.configure({
...
debug: false,
startForeground: false,
...
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You can't . Those messages are toast messages. Read about them.